# SQL one to many on one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have a table that records the diagnosis of patient for each attendance. Patients can have more than one diagnosis.

I want one row per attendance with all diagnosis (up to 12 diagnosis). The below brings back more than one row.

```
select
    dg.AttendanceID
    , dg.PatientNumber
    , dg.DiagnosisDate
    , dg.Diagnosis
from
    Diagnosis dg


AttendanceID    PatientNumber   DiagnosisDate   Diagnosis
10001           123456          01-Oct-13   A
10001           123456          01-Oct-13   B
10002           123456          20-Oct-13   D
```

It results should look like this:

```
AttendanceID    PatientNumber   DiagnosisDate   Diagnosis 1 Diagnosis 2 Diagnosis 3
10001           123456          01-Oct-13   A            B       
10002           123456          20-Oct-13   D
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: I believe PIVOT can do the job here?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the result by implementing the PIVOT function, but I would also suggest using the windowing function `row_number()` to generate the number of diagnosis for each `attendanceid` and `patientnumber`:

```
select attendanceid, patientnumber,
  diagnosisdate,
  Diagnosis1, Diagnosis2, Diagnosis3
from
(
  select attendanceid, patientnumber,
    diagnosisdate, diagnosis,
    'diagnosis'+
      cast(row_number() over(partition by attendanceid, patientnumber
                              order by diagnosis) as varchar(2)) seq
  from diagnosis
) d
pivot
(
  max(diagnosis)
  for seq in (Diagnosis1, Diagnosis2, Diagnosis3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d04402/2).  Since you know you will have up to 12 diagnosis per patient/attendance you can easily hard code the query to add the additional columns.

But if you needed a dynamic version of the code, then you could use something similar to the following:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(seq) 
                    from
                    (
                       select 'diagnosis'+
                          cast(row_number() over(partition by attendanceid, patientnumber
                               order by diagnosis) as varchar(2)) seq
                       from diagnosis
                    ) d
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT attendanceid, patientnumber,
               diagnosisdate,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select attendanceid, patientnumber,
                diagnosisdate, diagnosis,
                ''diagnosis''+
                  cast(row_number() over(partition by attendanceid, patientnumber
                                          order by diagnosis) as varchar(2)) seq
              from diagnosis
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(diagnosis)
                for seq in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/209c3/2)

Both versions give a result:

```
| ATTENDANCEID | PATIENTNUMBER |                  DIAGNOSISDATE | DIAGNOSIS1 | DIAGNOSIS2 | DIAGNOSIS3 |
|--------------|---------------|--------------------------------|------------|------------|------------|
|        10001 |        123456 | October, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |          A |          B |     (null) |
|        10002 |        123456 | October, 20 2013 00:00:00+0000 |          D |     (null) |     (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but it should be something along those lines.

```
;with cte as(
select
dg.AttendanceID
, dg.PatientNumber
, dg.DiagnosisDate
, dg.Diagnosis
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by dg.attendanceID order by attendanceID) as seq1
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by dg.attendanceID, patient_no order by diagnosis) as seq2
from
Diagnosis dg
)

 select
 t1.attendanceID
 ,t1.patientNumber
 ,t1.diagnosisDate
 ,(select Diagnosis from cte t2 where t1.attendanceID=t2.attendanceID and             t1.patientNumber=t2.patientNumber and t2.seq2='1') as diag1
 ,(select Diagnosis from cte t2 where t1.attendanceID=t2.attendanceID and    t1.patientNumber=t2.patientNumber and t2.seq2='2') as diag2
 ,(select Diagnosis from cte t2 where t1.attendanceID=t2.attendanceID and t1.patientNumber=t2.patientNumber and t2.seq2='3') as diag3
 ,(select Diagnosis from cte t2 where t1.attendanceID=t2.attendanceID and t1.patientNumber=t2.patientNumber and t2.seq2='4') as diag4
 ,(select Diagnosis from cte t2 where t1.attendanceID=t2.attendanceID and t1.patientNumber=t2.patientNumber and t2.seq2='5') as diag5
  from cte t1
  where seq1= 1
```

Comment: Dont you think you need group by?

Comment: This works, but i don't understand the complex syntax. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Below is a probable solution by using cursors i am not sure if you can show it as columns as it is variable for every patient  but this will show diagnosis as comma separated in one single column

```
DECLARE @combinedString VARCHAR(MAX),
@id int,
@Diagnosis VARCHAR(MAX)


Declare @CONCATRESULT TABLE (AttendanceID int, Question VARCHAR(MAX) )

Declare Dia cursor for 
SELECT  AttendanceID FROM  Diagnosis 

open Dia 
Fetch next from Dia into @id
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 
begin

SELECT   @combinedString = COALESCE(@combinedString + ', ', '') + Diagnosis,         
@id=AttendanceID  FROM [Prod_PostData].[dbo].[KMSFPostDataDenorm] d
WHERE AttendanceID = @id

insert into @CONCATRESULT values (  @id ,@combinedString )

SET @combinedString = null

Fetch next from Dia into @id
end
close Dia
deallocate Dia


select
dg.AttendanceID
, dg.PatientNumber
, dg.DiagnosisDate
, dg.Diagnosis
from
Diagnosis dg join (select * from @CONCATRESULT) Y on dg.AttendanceID=Y.AttendanceID
```